# C++ Buffer Overflow

Tags: c++, overflow, buffer, exploit

I'm trying to teach myself about buffer overflows and exploitation in C++. I'm an intermediate C++ guy, at best, so bear with me. I've followed a few tutorials, but here's some example code to illustrate my question:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std; 

int main()
{
  begin:
  int authentication = 0;
  char cUsername[10], cPassword[10];
  char cUser[10], cPass[10];

  cout << "Username: ";
  cin >> cUser;

  cout << "Pass: ";
  cin >> cPass;

  strcpy(cUsername, cUser);
  strcpy(cPassword, cPass);

  if(strcmp(cUsername, "admin") == 0 && strcmp(cPassword, "adminpass") == 0)
  {
    authentication = 1;
  }
  if(authentication)
  {
    cout << "Access granted\n";
    cout << (char)authentication;
  } 
  else 
  {
    cout << "Wrong username and password\n";
  }

  system("pause");
  goto begin;
}
```

I know there's all kinds of bad juju in here with `cin << String`, etc... Anyhow, when I enter too many letters (a ton of `A`'s for instance) into `cUser` and `cPass`, I just get an Access Violation from Visual Studio. If, however, I type 20ish `A`'s, then a space, then another `A` into `cUser`, it skips asking me for `cPass` (assuming because it's been filled after the space character caused the previous call to `cin` to return) and just grants me access.

At what point, and why, is data overflowing into "authentication" and why does it only happen when I have the space and not when I have a million `A`'s... I never get the "Access Violation" when I use a space in the input for `cUser`.

Comment: system("pause");
    goto begin;

Nope, pretty sure you are a beginner.

Comment: Are you trying to get the overflow and wondering why it does that? Or do you want no overflow and are asking for a solution? Also you shouldn't system(). It's a huge backdoor for a hacker.

Comment: Also, I have a program called `pause` on my system that launches nuclear missiles. So I probably shouldn't run your program.

Comment: why do you use char arrarys when you've included string header ??? also goto and system("pause")... I can't punish your self more than you did.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz ahaahahah

Comment: Have you walked through this, using a debugger, to see just what is in your variables as the program progresses?  Since you never enter anything like the values used to get authentication set to 1, nor should the overflows affect that variable (since its declared first), I'd be curious as to what you find.

Comment: Hate to jump in and kind of hijack the topic but how is system() a backdoor for hackers? I know it's generally bad practice to use and that's all

Comment: Your code would be significantly easier to read and maintain if you use the `std::string` class instead of char arrays.

Comment: system("command") is for windows only that's why is not good practice. not shore about hacker's backdoor umph.

Comment: @Michael a user could replace the system function "pause" with their own malicious code, so when it's run, their code runs instead of pausing the program. In a huge program with large implications and money involved, it would obviously be a bad idea to have that in the code.

Comment: @codekiddy `system("command")` is required by the C standard and inherited by C++, on all platforms. But its behavior is completely platform-specific. On some platforms, a hacker could install a file that would be found and executed instead of the intended one.

Comment: I'd never actually thought of that before. So if someone knew a user had a professional program that (would probably never) use system(pause) or the likes they could name their program "pause" and replace it in the root directory? to have this called when using a legitimate program, quite worrying considering all the horrible code I churn out :P

Comment: @Redmastif
I'm trying to figure out why the space makes a difference. Why do I get an "Access Violation" without it, but if I have a space, then the software is essentially exploited with the overflow by writing into authentication.

Why is an "Access Violation" being flagged in one instance but not the other? What's the difference?

Comment: @sraboy Using `cin` stops reading when it encounters whitespace. Try using `getline(cin,cUser)` instead. Also check [this](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/getline/) link out

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I modified your program a little bit to make it more illustrative:

```
#include <iostream>

int main( void )
{
 int authentication = 0;
 char cUsername[ 10 ];
 char cPassword[ 10 ];

 std::cout << "Username: ";
 std::cin >> cUsername;

 std::cout << "Pass: ";
 std::cin >> cPassword;

 if( std::strcmp( cUsername, "admin" ) == 0 && std::strcmp( cPassword, "adminpass" ) == 0 )
 {
  authentication = 1;
 }
 if( authentication )
 {
  std::cout << "Access granted\n";
  std::cout << ( char )authentication;
 }
 else
 {
  std::cout << "Wrong username and password\n";
 }

 return ( 0 );
}
```

I compiled it with x64 compiler command-line MS compiler, no optimizations. So now we have an exe that we want to "hack". We load the program with WinDbg (really good debugger) and take a look at the disassembly (notice, I've supplied full debug info, for clarity):

```
00000001`3f1f1710 4883ec68        sub     rsp,68h
00000001`3f1f1714 488b0515db0300  mov     rax,qword ptr [Prototype_Console!__security_cookie (00000001`3f22f230)]
00000001`3f1f171b 4833c4          xor     rax,rsp
00000001`3f1f171e 4889442450      mov     qword ptr [rsp+50h],rax
00000001`3f1f1723 c744243800000000 mov     dword ptr [rsp+38h],0  // This gives us address of "authentication" on stack.
00000001`3f1f172b 488d156e1c0300  lea     rdx,[Prototype_Console!std::_Iosb<int>::end+0x78 (00000001`3f2233a0)]
00000001`3f1f1732 488d0d47f00300  lea     rcx,[Prototype_Console!std::cout (00000001`3f230780)]
00000001`3f1f1739 e8fdf9ffff      call    Prototype_Console!ILT+310(??$?6U?$char_traitsDstdstdYAAEAV?$basic_ostreamDU?$char_traitsDstd (00000001`3f1f113b)
00000001`3f1f173e 488d542428      lea     rdx,[rsp+28h] // This gives us address of "cUsername" on stack.
00000001`3f1f1743 488d0df6f00300  lea     rcx,[Prototype_Console!std::cin (00000001`3f230840)]
00000001`3f1f174a e823faffff      call    Prototype_Console!ILT+365(??$?5DU?$char_traitsDstdstdYAAEAV?$basic_istreamDU?$char_traitsDstd (00000001`3f1f1172)
00000001`3f1f174f 488d153e1c0300  lea     rdx,[Prototype_Console!std::_Iosb<int>::end+0x6c (00000001`3f223394)]
00000001`3f1f1756 488d0d23f00300  lea     rcx,[Prototype_Console!std::cout (00000001`3f230780)]
00000001`3f1f175d e8d9f9ffff      call    Prototype_Console!ILT+310(??$?6U?$char_traitsDstdstdYAAEAV?$basic_ostreamDU?$char_traitsDstd (00000001`3f1f113b)
00000001`3f1f1762 488d542440      lea     rdx,[rsp+40h] // This gives us address of "cPassword" on stack.
00000001`3f1f1767 488d0dd2f00300  lea     rcx,[Prototype_Console!std::cin (00000001`3f230840)]
00000001`3f1f176e e8fff9ffff      call    Prototype_Console!ILT+365(??$?5DU?$char_traitsDstdstdYAAEAV?$basic_istreamDU?$char_traitsDstd (00000001`3f1f1172)
00000001`3f1f1773 488d15321c0300  lea     rdx,[Prototype_Console!std::_Iosb<int>::end+0x84 (00000001`3f2233ac)]
00000001`3f1f177a 488d4c2428      lea     rcx,[rsp+28h]
00000001`3f1f177f e86c420000      call    Prototype_Console!strcmp (00000001`3f1f59f0)
00000001`3f1f1784 85c0            test    eax,eax
00000001`3f1f1786 751d            jne     Prototype_Console!main+0x95 (00000001`3f1f17a5)
00000001`3f1f1788 488d15291c0300  lea     rdx,[Prototype_Console!std::_Iosb<int>::end+0x90 (00000001`3f2233b8)]
00000001`3f1f178f 488d4c2440      lea     rcx,[rsp+40h]
00000001`3f1f1794 e857420000      call    Prototype_Console!strcmp (00000001`3f1f59f0)
00000001`3f1f1799 85c0            test    eax,eax
00000001`3f1f179b 7508            jne     Prototype_Console!main+0x95 (00000001`3f1f17a5)
00000001`3f1f179d c744243801000000 mov     dword ptr [rsp+38h],1
00000001`3f1f17a5 837c243800      cmp     dword ptr [rsp+38h],0
00000001`3f1f17aa 7426            je      Prototype_Console!main+0xc2 (00000001`3f1f17d2)
00000001`3f1f17ac 488d15151c0300  lea     rdx,[Prototype_Console!std::_Iosb<int>::end+0xa0 (00000001`3f2233c8)]
00000001`3f1f17b3 488d0dc6ef0300  lea     rcx,[Prototype_Console!std::cout (00000001`3f230780)]
00000001`3f1f17ba e87cf9ffff      call    Prototype_Console!ILT+310(??$?6U?$char_traitsDstdstdYAAEAV?$basic_ostreamDU?$char_traitsDstd (00000001`3f1f113b)
00000001`3f1f17bf 0fb6542438      movzx   edx,byte ptr [rsp+38h]
00000001`3f1f17c4 488d0db5ef0300  lea     rcx,[Prototype_Console!std::cout (00000001`3f230780)]
00000001`3f1f17cb e825f9ffff      call    Prototype_Console!ILT+240(??$?6U?$char_traitsDstdstdYAAEAV?$basic_ostreamDU?$char_traitsDstd (00000001`3f1f10f5)
00000001`3f1f17d0 eb13            jmp     Prototype_Console!main+0xd5 (00000001`3f1f17e5)
00000001`3f1f17d2 488d15ff1b0300  lea     rdx,[Prototype_Console!std::_Iosb<int>::end+0xb0 (00000001`3f2233d8)]
00000001`3f1f17d9 488d0da0ef0300  lea     rcx,[Prototype_Console!std::cout (00000001`3f230780)]
00000001`3f1f17e0 e856f9ffff      call    Prototype_Console!ILT+310(??$?6U?$char_traitsDstdstdYAAEAV?$basic_ostreamDU?$char_traitsDstd (00000001`3f1f113b)
00000001`3f1f17e5 33c0            xor     eax,eax
00000001`3f1f17e7 488b4c2450      mov     rcx,qword ptr [rsp+50h]
00000001`3f1f17ec 4833cc          xor     rcx,rsp
00000001`3f1f17ef e8bc420000      call    Prototype_Console!__security_check_cookie (00000001`3f1f5ab0)
00000001`3f1f17f4 4883c468        add     rsp,68h
00000001`3f1f17f8 c3              ret
```

Now, since we know how x64 stack works we can start "hacking". `RSP` is stack pointer, function stack is addresses above `RSP` value (stack grows into smaller addresses). So, we see that `RSP+28h` is where `cUsername`, `RSP+38h` is `authentication`, and `RSP+40h` is `cPassword`, where 28h, 38h and 40h are hexadecimal offsets. Here is little image to illustrate:

```
-----> old RSP value // Stack frame of caller of `main` is above, stack frame of main is below 

      16 bytes of
      "cPassword"
+40h
     8 bytes of "authentication"
+38h
      16 bytes of
      "cUsername"
+28h   


-----> RSP value = old RSP-68h
```

What do we see from here? We see that compiler aligned data on 8 byte boundary: for example, we asked to allocate 10 bytes for `cUsername`, but we got 16 bytes - x64 bit stack is aligned on 8-byte boundary, naturally. That means in order to write into `authentication` we need to write into `cUsername` MORE that 16 bytes (symbols). Notice also, that compiler put `cPassword` higher that `authentication` - we cannot overwrite `authentication` using `cPassword`, only `cUsername`.

So now we run our program and input `Username: 0123456789abcdef1`. `0123456789abcdef` = 16 bytes, the next `1` is going to be put into lower byte of `authentication` - good enough for us:

```
Username: 0123456789abcdef1
Pass: whatever
Access granted
1
```

Comment: Thanks so much for going through all the trouble to explain what was apparently an incredibly simple question. I appreciate the ASM breakout and the example. You're quite the instructor!

Comment: @sraboy If you are interested in how compiler generates code, memory layout etc, then little test programs like yours are the way to go. Just read a little bit about most common assembler instructions and stack layout for your CPU, and get a debugger that will allow you to disassemble. Then you'll be able to see how your C/C++ code is transformed into actual machine instructions. It allows not only to use some "tricks", but also gives you idea, for example, about what things compiler is able to optimize etc.

Comment: Hi, I am new to c++. I got a silly question to ask, how can we limit the user input to the variable size that we have declared? For example, cUsername is only accepting 10 chars, but user can enter more than that right? It is possible to prevent overflow from this variable?

Comment: @overshadow Yes. For example, you can use `std::setw()`: `std::cin >> std::setw(9) >> cUsername;`.

Comment: It is AMAZING how a ancient/obnoxious language as C++ survived that long. Maybe it is time for its reign to end, to make room to modern languages (not so prone to errors such as buffer overflow).

Answer (score 2):

It is overwriting your `authentication` variable. This means that `authentication` is positive even before your code checks the username and password. To check this, print out authentication prior to the checks.

I'll expand a little further: When you type is a very long username, that long username is copied, by your `strcpy`, into `cUsername`. That variable `cUsername` is immediately after `authentication` and hence it is overwritten by the overly-long username.

If you type a very very long username, then (again) the authentication variable will be overwritten. But also now the items further up the stack, such as the return value, will be overwritten. If your program overwrites too high up the stack, then it will be very badly broken and anything can happen. You essentially execute random code at this point.

Comment: Why does having a space in there prevent an "Access Violation" from being identified as opposed to simply overwriting authentication?

Comment: I don't think the space is relevant. All whitespace is treated the same by `cin`. I think your question is "When I have about 20 chars in the username, then the program proceeds to authentication, and when I have many more characters (say 100) then I get an access violation. Why this difference?"

Comment: Alrighty then. Thanks for the reply... being self-taught, I can write code from here to kingdom-come, but I can't debug for my life and don't know much about the stack and memory allocation. Appreciate the info.

Comment: @sraboy, which compiler were you using? I did experiments and g++ and clang. Where you using clang? Which version of which compiler?

Comment: I just used Visual Studio 2010, so MSVC++... whichever compiler I'm at now, not sure what updates/service packs I have at this point. I generally just go with C# or VB.NET/GDI for my apps, so this C++ stuff with memory management, etc is quite new to me. I'm used to all the managed code.

Comment: THanks for that, I noticed that the relative layout of the variables was different between different compilers. (I think that's just a case of optimization differences.) I was able to get your behaviour with code compiled by clang, but not by g++. I'm running on Linux. Anyway, Azza's answer is great!

Answer (score 1):

If you use `std::string`, you'll find that your program will be much simpler:

```
int main()
{
  bool authenticated = false;

  while(!authenticated)
  {
    string username;
    string password;

    cout << "Username: ";
    getline(cin, username); // you may want to read input differently

    cout << "Pass: ";
    getline(cin, password); // same as above

    // you'll need to check cin.fail() to see whether the stream
    // had failed to read data, and exit the loop with "break".

    if(username == "admin" && password == "adminpass")
    {
      authenticated = true;
    }
    else
    {
      cout << "Wrong username and password, try again\n";
    }
  }

  if(authenticated)
  {
    cout << "Access granted\n";
  }      
}
```

#### Edit:

With regards to your recent question, I think by default, `cin >> string` will stop reading at the first whitespace character (i.e. space), so if you input a space, `cin` will stop before it corrupts any data, and so you don't get the access violation. If you want to be able to read spaces, then you'll need to use `getline` like I have above so that it will read the entire line of text, spaces included.

Comment: Thanks. I know how to avoid this issue altogether, but I'm trying to figure out the specifics behind the difference in supplying a space to cin. Without the space, I get an Access Violation. With the space, I get my exploit.

Comment: Ah! Thanks. I hadn't realized that. So cin simply ceases reading at the whitespace and this keeps it from reading too much into memory when I try cin >> uPass. I knew that it stopped at whitespace but didn't put 2 and 2 together on a few things. Running through with the debugger I can see what's going on now. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Proposed solution to detect NULL pointer and buffer overflow in memcpy, memset, strcpy before hand and print out the location (file:line) where the problem occurs:

> http://htvdanh.blogspot.com/2016/09/proposed-solution-to-detect-null.html

Answer (score 0):

When you compile a program, the compiler decides how to arrange your data in memory. If a program contains unchecked array accesses, it may be exploitable as a malicious user with knowledge of the arrangement of data in memory can figure out how to overwrite critical variables.

However, C++ doesn't give you complete control over how things are laid out on the stack. Local variables may appear in any order in memory.

To understand buffer overflow exploits, you will have to disassemble your program and delve into machine code. This will give you the layout of the stack, including the all-important return addresses.

By the way, the "Access Violation" is coming from your program, not Visual Studio. You probably need more experience with "forward" engineering before getting into reverse engineering.

Comment: "forward" engineering :D I have to remember that.

Comment: I'll be sure to work on my forward engineering... appreciate the witticism. I'm trying to understand why I get an "Access Violation" in one instance and not in the other (with the space).

Comment: @sraboy Not intended as a witticism or a jab… anyway the results are unpredictable because you didn't start with enough information to make a prediction. You're shooting in the dark, do you really expect to obtain definite results?

Comment: I didn't know what to expect. It was all new to me. Your response didn't quite explain it. I had a practical question; your answer was abstract. Combined with AzzA's, it helps, especially knowing that your reference to "local variables may appear in any order" was explained better by him informing me that the compiler simply chose to place cPassword above authentication.

I don't know much about the stack and just program until it works. This is my first attempt at figuring this stuff out from a practical perspective.

I'm a .NET (and QBASIC) guy, so memory management, etc is new to me.

Answer (score 0):

Because you have your char set to 10 places (including the `NULL` character), anything longer will overflow onto `Authentication`. There are numerous ways to fix this, most obviously being so simply make the char bigger. Other ways would be to limit the number of letters a user enters at registration (assuming this was on a website server). You could also use `strlen(cUsername)` to count the length of the char array and ask for re-entry of the username with less characters.
EDIT:
Ok. So what you want to do is use `getline(cin,cUser)` instead. `cin` stops reading at the first occurence of a whitespace. `getline()` will read the entire string with or without spaces.

Comment: I understand there's plenty of ways to avoid this; I'm just trying to understand the concepts here. Why am I getting that "Access Violation" when there's no space but it simply allows extra data to be written over into authentication if I have a space?

Comment: Using `strlen(cUsername)` to check whether the user has entered too many characters won't work because by then it is too late. You want to stop reading when `cUsername` is full, not to check if it is overfull afterwards.